Unable to install prokka using homebrew or conda
I have tried to install prokka using homebrew using the code brew install prokka (I also tried brew install brewsci/bio/prokka) and it gave this error:
curl: (7) Failed to connect to mbio-serv2.mbioekol.lu.se port 80 after 75009 ms: Couldn't connect to server 
Error: prokka: Failed to download resource "aragorn" 
Download failed: http://mbio-serv2.mbioekol.lu.se/ARAGORN/Downloads/aragorn1.2.38.tgz

I then tried installing with conda using the code
conda create -n prokka_env 
conda activate prokka_env 
mamba install prokka

and it gave the error:
Could not solve for environment specs
The following package could not be installed
└─ prokka does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel).


Prokka's github page  github page has:
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults prokka

edit
Seems that there may be another way to do it:
stepwise components install 

I've tried that as well but I get the error:
'''CondaValueError: You have chosen a non-default solver backend (libmamba) but it was not recognized. Choose one of: classic'''

I have tried on Mac (
ProductName:  macOS
ProductVersion:  14.5
BuildVersion:  23F79 ).
No errors.

conda config --set restore_free_channel true

@LucyKelly  • Choose one of: classic •

libmamba vs classic -->  https://conda.github.io/conda-libmamba-solver/user-guide/libmamba-vs-classic/

@LucyKelly do you have mamba installed and on the PATH?
